# Do the afflicted become random events?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When completing the daedric quest "The Only Cure" you meet a series of NPCs designated "The Afflicted".  I was wandering Skyrim north of Solitude when I encountered two "Afflicted Remnants" fighting with each other before attacking me.

Was this a fluke or do these "afflicted remnants" become random events such as bandits & thieves in the wilds of Skyrim?  The Elder Scrolls Wikia says that a group will be sent out to hunt the dragonborn after the quest, but now that I have dispatched them once will they reappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start The Only Cure, you have a chance to see an Afflicted running from Bthardamz. After completing the quest, there is a chance that a group of refugee Afflicted will attack you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after the quest "The Only Cure" those green-puking remnants will become random events.